# Battery usage of my application when app is not optimized

Tags: android, optimization, battery

I have an application that wake up device in doze mode and working in background for getting location and send data to server. Anyway, i want to know how much battery usage of my application in some devices that i already installed. I checked battery usage of my application in settings of device but in some devices with battery optimization option was disable, the battery usage is very low like 0% or 2%! 
Can i trust to this feature in settings for battery used or when battery usage is not optimized for my app, is this feature incorrect?

Comment: basically there is no way to accurately measure the battery consumed by the app, as not only it's process works on the device simultanuously. Some battery is consumed by the system itself, some - by other apps. So you can only know that aproximately.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @VladyslavMatviienko. Not important, i want to know how much my application used battery in not optimized mode aproximately.

Comment: Then I think it is fine to trust those 0%-2% usage